# Bitwise logic on maze walls

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, maze

I have an enum which represents the current state of a cell within a maze, something like this:

```
[Flags]
public enum CellInfo : ushort
{
    None = 0,
    NorthWall = 1,
    EastWall = 2,
    SouthWall = 4,
    WestWall = 8,
    AllWalls = NorthWall | EastWall | SouthWall | WestWall
}
```

With it I can track the current state of each cells' walls pretty easily, for example if I want to open a wall east.

```
var myCell = CellInfo.AllWalls; // initialise a cell with all walls up
myCell ^= CellInfo.EastWall; // east wall now down!
```

Easy! But, each cell is next to another cell, which has its own wall, so in actual fact I always know im moving from cell `a` to cell `b`, and for arguments sake lets say this is an eastwards movement, I need to take down the east wall of `a` and the *west* wall of `b`:

```
var a = CellInfo.AllWalls;
var b = CellInfo.AllWalls;
// assume a->b is eastwards
a ^= CellInfo.EastWall;
b ^= CellInfo.WestWall;
```

Now, I have a generic way of handling this movement, however I don't like it, its got a code smell! Too many `if` statements, and I was wondering if I've missed something obvious - some bitwise logic I may not have spotted perhaps? I have pasted my `KnockDownWall` method below and it takes the grid of cells (`CellInfo[,]`) along with the grid *position* of `a` and `b` expressed as `Tuple<int,int>` (x,y position)

---

```
protected static void KnockDownWall(CellInfo[,] cells, Tuple<int, int> target, Tuple<int, int> neighbour)
{
    var offsetTarget = Tuple.Create(neighbour.Item1 - target.Item1, neighbour.Item2 - target.Item2);
    if(offsetTarget.Item1 == 0)
    {
        if(offsetTarget.Item2 == -1)
        {
            cells[target.Item1, target.Item2] ^= CellInfo.NorthWall;
            cells[neighbour.Item1, neighbour.Item2] ^= CellInfo.SouthWall;
        }
        else
        {
            cells[target.Item1, target.Item2] ^= CellInfo.SouthWall;
            cells[neighbour.Item1, neighbour.Item2] ^= CellInfo.NorthWall;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (offsetTarget.Item1 == -1)
        {
            cells[target.Item1, target.Item2] ^= CellInfo.WestWall;
            cells[neighbour.Item1, neighbour.Item2] ^= CellInfo.EastWall;
        }
        else
        {
            cells[target.Item1, target.Item2] ^= CellInfo.EastWall;
            cells[neighbour.Item1, neighbour.Item2] ^= CellInfo.WestWall;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Plenty of useful info so farin answers - however I fear I oversimplified the problem to start with. `CellInfo` has many more values which store such things as N/S/E/W border (Allows me freedom to shape maze, and fence off areas), N/S/E/W solution and backtrack info - this all feeds into the model which draws the maze. Treating everything as cells rather than walls has some benefit.

Comment: I would suggest a change to `KnockDownWall` to `KnockDownWall(CellInfo[,] cells, Position from, Direction direction)`.

Comment: @Dzienny - that just leaves me with a slightly less cumbersome `if...then` but no better off. Seeing as all my other code has reference to the `target` and its `neighbour` the logic to determine direction - much like the above - would just get pushed elsewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your approach to modeling the maze is that each inner wall is represented twice, requiring significant effort for maintaining internal consistency. A better approach is to expand the maze by an extra row at the south side and an extra column at the east side, and use two wall types instead of four - i.e. the wall on the north and the wall on the east side of the cell:

[image: Walls to be removed]

This picture shows a grid of 2 rows by 3 columns, extended to 3 rows by 4 columns. Red lines show the walls to be taken down.

In order to deal with walls in all four directions from a specific cell, make a method that recognizes south and west walls as north and east walls of the adjacent cell.

Finally, you could make two 2D arrays of `bool`s - one representing horizontal walls, and one representing vertical walls. This way the individual cells would not have to store their own walls at all, and the maze would always be internally consistent:

```
private const int rows = 10;
private const int cols = 15;
private bool northWalls[,] = new bool[rows+1, cols+1];
private bool westWalls[,] = new bool[rows+1, cols+1];
public bool HasWall(int cellRow, int cellCol, CellInfo dir) {
    switch(dir) {
        case CellInfo.NorthWall:
            return northWalls[cellRow,cellCol];
        case CellInfo.WestWall:
            return westWalls[cellRow,cellCol];
        case CellInfo.EasthWall:
            return westWalls[cellRow,cellCol+1];
        case CellInfo.SouthhWall:
            return northWalls[cellRow+1,cellCol];
    }
}
```

If you must work with the current design, but would like to get rid of the conditionals in the `KnockDownWall`, you could make two 3×3 arrays with values of `CellInfo.XyzWall` from your implementation, and index them with `offsetTarget.Item1+1, offsetTarget.Item2+1`:

```
protected static void KnockDownWall(CellInfo[,] cells, Tuple<int, int> target, Tuple<int, int> neighbour) {
    var offsetTarget = Tuple.Create(neighbour.Item1 - target.Item1, neighbour.Item2 - target.Item2);
    cells[target.Item1, target.Item2] ^= targetLookup[offsetTarget.Item1+1, offsetTarget.Item2+1];
    cells[neighbour.Item1, neighbour.Item2] ^= neighborLookup[offsetTarget.Item1+1, offsetTarget.Item2+1];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, useful way of thinking of it, I have updated the question a lwith where I oversimplified, and hopefully explains why I like dealing with individual cells, represented as a `ushort`ish Enum with many more possible values than just the walls

Comment: @Jamiec You have a `ushort`ish Enum with many values encoded in it? *shudder*. That sounds like a design that's *really hard* to work with. Why not have an object with properties? It'd be much easier to do *nearly anything*.

Comment: @TimS. partly as a learning exercise, my biwise logic needs work, clearly. Also, the logic for dealing with the value of each cell is well abstracted away, for example I have a `RandomizedKruskalMazeBuilder` which simply implements an algorithm, it doesnt go anywhere near the cells themselves - the only thing it does is call methods on its base class which end up drawing the maze. Somewhere down that chain of calls we get to `KnockDownWall` and it works fine - it just looks *ugly*!

Comment: I morre-or-less refactored to this solution, each cell creates its North & West edge, and the  South/East edges are referenced from the neighbouring cells. It, obviously, has simplified all other code such as building/solving the maze. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Your model says that each cell has 4 walls, all to itself. But that's not accurate, since those walls may be shared with other cells. You're seeing the painful point of that problem with the model. Also, your cells don't have any other information about them (from what you've shown us): you really just have walls. And they only have one property: whether they are up or knocked down.

I'd suggest that **your model should be based on walls**, not cells.

Here's an ASCII representation of your cells and walls, as I imagine them.

```
 ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─  // wall row 0, walls 0-5
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ // wall row 1, walls 0-6; cell row 0, cells 0-5
 ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─  // wall row 2, walls 0-5
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ // wall row 3, walls 0-6; cell row 1, cells 0-5
 ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─  // wall row 4, walls 0-5
```

Note that the number of walls is different in alternating rows. One way to deal with this is to use a jagged array instead of a multi-dimensional array.

```
bool[][] walls = // whatever
```

So to knock down the last vertical wall in row 1, just do:

```
walls[1][6] = false;
```

Or to toggle it:

```
walls[1][6] = !walls[1][6];
```

If you'll need to calculate the index in `walls` relative to the cell (e.g. the wall east from cell `1,2`), you can make a simple method that does so.

---

If you have properties to store about each cell and wall, you can have something like this:

```
Wall[][] walls;
Cell[,] cells;
```

`Wall` might have an `Active` or `Standing` property that you can toggle. If the `Wall` and `Cell` objects are aware of their position, you could even have `Cell.Walls`, `Cell.NorthWall` (etc.), or `Wall.Cells` properties that give you the surrounding elements.

Comment: Clever way of thinking of it, I have updated the question with a little more info. Basically, Im kind of wedded to dealing with cells rather than walls